# Sum up or increment a variable in XSLT using a function

Tags: xslt, increment, saxon

I have a .GPX file which I process using Saxon9.7 and the following .xsl file. I try to sum up distances between the different trackpoints by calculation the distance between two track points ( with @lon & @lat values).

Using this function I try to increment (or add up) these values.

- gDistance is the currently summed up distance
- distance is the number which should be added to the gDistance

The function should return the added distance

```
<xsl:function name="of:gesDistance">
    <xsl:param name="gDistance"/>
    <xsl:param name="distance"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($gDistance + $distance)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

my .xsl file looks something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
xmlns:of ="http://lul.org">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:function name="of:gesDistance">
    <xsl:param name="gDistance"/>
    <xsl:param name="distance"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($gDistance + $distance)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="trkseg">
    <xsl:variable name="gDistance" select="0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="trkpt">
        <xsl:variable name="dLat" select="(@lat - preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lat)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dLon" select="(@lon - preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lon)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cLon" select="(@lon)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cLat" select="(@lat)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pLon" select="(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lon)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pLat" select="(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@lat)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="distance" select="6378.388 * math:acos(math:sin($cLat)*math:sin($pLat) + math:cos($cLat) * math:cos($pLat) * math:cos($dLon))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="gDistance" select="of:gesDistance($gDistance, $distance)"/>

        <xsl:text>newNode&#xA;dLat: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dLat"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;dLon: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dLon"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;Distance: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$distance"/>
        <xsl:text> km &#xA;Length: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$gDistance"/>

    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In the for-each part I always calculate the distances **dLon**, **dLat** to the preceding tracepoint. Later on the distance in km is calculated.

The xsl:variable gDistance is set to 0 before the for-each statement

```
        <xsl:variable name="gDistance" select="0"/>
```

The following line describes the part where the function gets called with the old gDistance value and the current distance to the preceding sibling.

```
<xsl:variable name="gDistance" select="of:gesDistance($gDistance, $distance)"/>
```

running this using Saxon9 gives me the following output:

```
dLat: -0.0001660000000001105
dLon: -0.0004770000000000607
Distance: 1.1425320012289337 km 
Length: 1.1425320012289337
newNode
dLat: -0.00023200000000400678
dLon: -0.0006450000000004508
Distance: 1.5892769562498525 km 
Length: 1.5892769562498525
newNode
dLat: -0.00023799999999596366
dLon: -0.0004939999999997724
Distance: 1.5814420943745287 km 
Length: 1.5814420943745287
```

As you can see the summed up distance is always the same as the distance to the preceding sibling. But why? Is there a way or a workaround for my problem?

I tried different approaches to my problem using different Saxon-commands but that didn't work either.

Is there a prepared xml-namespace with the function I need?

... To give you everything I have - a part of my GPX file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
 <trk>
  <name>ACTIVE LOG133212</name>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lat="48.813909" lon="9.249088">
    <ele>-21.666</ele>
    <time>2008-05-25T13:32:07Z</time>
   </trkpt>
   <trkpt lat="48.814533" lon="9.248918">
    <ele>49.192</ele>
    <time>2008-05-25T13:32:14Z</time>
   </trkpt>
...
```

Comment: Variables are NOT variable in XSLT.  You must write an expression that calculates the total you want, you cannot accumulate values piecemeal as you would in procedural languages.  XSLT is functional, not procedural.

Comment: If you really want to use that imperative programming approach with Saxon 9.7 then you need PE or EE and use XSLT 3.0 and `xsl:iterate`. But as Jim has said, in XSLT 2.0 you can write expressions and/or recursive functions/templates that add/accumulate values just fine.

Comment: @JimGarrison so I have to make an expression which calculates the distances for an unknown number of nodes and sums them up. Am I right? Isn't there any other way to make something like this work?

Comment: A simple way to "increment a variable" (or, more precisely, accumulate a balance) is to employ a technique known as *sibling recursion*. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809106/3016153

Comment: P.S. Are you sure your formula for calculating the distance is correct?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Watching the timestamps and the longitude and latitude changes these distances made sense to me.

Comment: I am afraid none of that makes sense to *me*. And I am quite sure you need to convert the angles to radians before applying any trigonometric functions to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier if we simplify the example. The canonical example I use is the "bank statement" problem: given a sequence of transactions with money coming into or going out of an account, show a bank statement with all the transactions plus a running total of the amount in the account.

The simplest solution to this is to compute

```
$balance = $initial-balance + sum(preceding-sibling::transaction/value)
```

but computing that for each transaction is O(n^2) in cost, so you don't want to use this solution unless the number of transactions is very small.

In functional programming there are two main approaches to tackle this. One is recursion: you can compute the sequence of balances as a function of the sequence of transactions with a recursive function:

```
<xsl:function name="f:balances" as="xs:decimal*">
   <xsl:param name="initial-balance" as="xs:decimal*"/>
   <xsl:param name="transactions" as="element(transaction)*"/>
   <xsl:variable name="first-balance" select="initial-balance + head(transactions)/value"/>
   <xsl:sequence select="$first-balance"/>
   <xsl:sequence select="f:balances($first-balance, tail($transactions)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

This function computes the balance after the first transaction and then calls itself to compute the balances for the remainder of the transactions - classic head/tail recursion.

Another way to do this is with the fold operation. A fold operation takes an initial value and a sequence, and it applies a supplied function to each item in the sequence in turn, each time with a new initial value. So

```
fn:fold-left($transactions, $initial-balance, function($balance, $transaction) {$balance + $transaction/value})
```

XSLT 3.0 also introduces xsl:iterate as syntactic sugar for the fold operation:

```
<xsl:iterate select="$transactions">
  <xsl:param name="initial-balance"/>
  <xsl:variable name="balance" select="./value + $initial-balance"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$balance"/>
  <xsl:next-iteration>
    <xsl:with-param name="initial-balance" select="$balance"/>
  </xsl:next-iteration>
</xsl:iterate>
```

If you find these concepts a little daunting, that's because imperative programming has distorted your brain to the point where you regard a statement like

```
i = i + 1
```

as normal and acceptable.